# run android emulator on mac

Tags: android, macos, cordova

I am trying to run a phonegap application for android on my OSX. 
when I try to run phonegap through CLI I get this

```
    No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator


Error: No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: /Users/susanne/Documents/roger/02_Onni/09_development/application/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: /Users/susanne/Documents/roger/02_Onni/09_development/application/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver
```

I have done no 1. but I cannot find the 'android avd' file mentioned in number 2. Also even though I connect an android device it does not find it.

I would be very happy if anyone could help. This is probably not a phonegap specific question but rather an Android question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is because of you didn't created device. So you have to firstly create the device in android sdk.

For creation of android device you have to install the avd first.
i have some screenshot hope help you.

1. Prepare your Android API like this[image]:
2. Then go to Tools->Manage avds :
   [image]
3. In my case i have created 2 devices already. go to Create:

[image]

4. and then add specification that which kind of device you want here is dummy for your understanding :

[image]

click Ok and your device will created. then run your app again.

thanks.

Comment: where do I see step 2 in your picture? I've done step 1 for sure. step 2 picture I cannot find tools > manage

Comment: go to the Menu->Tools->Manage avds . You find the menu bar in Top.